# Is 日本二 acceptable?

Tags: word-choice

日本一 means the best in Japan. So, can you use 日本二 for the second best thing in Japan? If not, how do I describe the second one? "日本第二位のもの" sounds like something that Japan has taken second place in.

Comment: Don't settle for 2nd best!!  もっと頑張ってください！ You can do it!  

Comment: The title unintentionally had a different meaning Next time I will aim to be 日本一!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No.

日本二の will be understood with appropriate contexts, but can be used only in casual speech and half-jokingly.

日本第二位の sounds ok, and at least does not sound like you describe. 日本が第二位である would be used for something for which Japan has the 2nd place.　But the following will be more common:

- 大阪は日本第二の都市だ : Osaka is the 2nd largest city in Japan. (Note: maybe it should be Yokohama in reality. It depends on what *large* means.)
- 日本はかつて世界第二位の経済大国だった : Japan was once the 2nd largest economy in the world.
- 日本は X で世界第二位を占める : Japan occupies the 2nd place in X

Comment: Thank you. Is there any difference between 日本第二位の and 日本第二の?

Comment: Both mean the same, just 位 tends to be omitted. Also when you clarify what the 2nd place is about, 日本で二番目に大きい can be used (大きい can be replaced with appropriate phrases).